# Passing a list<string> into Linq

Tags: c#, linq

The first query returns a list of string, and I am passing them into another table to find corresponding items, but nothing happens. no error message or nothing

```
var classIds = _contextSpecRepo.Get(x => x.cId.Equals(cId)).Select(x => x.classNames).Distinct().ToList();
// issue happens in the following query
var classes= Repository.Get(x => x.Id.Equals(classIds)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `Equals`, which takes `object`, hides the problem: you are comparing a single `Id` to a list of `Id`s, rather than checking if the `Id` is present in a collection. This compiles, but yields no result.

Here is how you can fix it:

```
var classes= Repository.Get(x => classIds.Any(y => y == x.Id)).ToList();
```

or

```
var classes= Repository.Get(x => classIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you must do it in 2 queries then you have to use contains

```
var classes= Repository.Get(x => classIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

A better solution would be to use a join on the tables.

Answer (score 1):

you can also skip .ToList()

```
var classes= Repository.Get(x => classIds.Contains(x.Id));
```